# Strange of Mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I have this query run from PHP:

```
"SELECT * FROM punti WHERE uud='2a1c866f-9f08-4c81-aeeb-48ec3b98ab43'"

$con = mysqli_connect( $serverd, $userd, $passd, $datad )or die( "Unable to connect to the MySQL Server!" );
//$uud = mysqli_real_escape_string( $con, urldecode( $_POST[ 'uud' ] ) );

$query = mysqli_query( $con, "SELECT * FROM punti WHERE uud='2a1c866f-9f08-4c81-aeeb-48ec3b98ab43'" );
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows( $query );
if ( $numrows > 0 ) {
    $array = array();   
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query ) ) {
        $data = $row[ 'data' ];
        $punti = $row[ 'punti' ];
        $array = array_merge($array, array($data => $punti));   
    }
    echo json_encode( $array );     
} else {
    echo "Vuoto";
}
```

result: `{"35\/03\/2018":"3","31\/03\/2018":"6"}`

and it return 2 result but in database there are 4 result

look at the photos to understand:

[image]

Database result for same query:

[image]

Comment: `35/03/2018`? What day is this?

Comment: It is a varchar(15) not date, i have changed the string only for testing

Comment: Added code php =)

Comment: may be there are space around other uud.Try this way after removing space.  "SELECT * FROM punti WHERE trim(uud)='2a1c866f-9f08-4c81-aeeb-48ec3b98ab43'"

Comment: `$array = array_merge($array, array($data => $punti));` that's the issue here. Why merge?

Comment: Because i need a single json =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is in your `array_merge` function. When you merge arrays, you **overwrite** values with same **string** key. And you have same **string** key, it is `31/03/2018`.

Use simple `[]` notation to add new array to result:

```
$array[] = array($data => $punti);
// instead
//$array = array_merge($array, array($data => $punti));
```

But beware, your `json` will have another structure, something like:

```
[{"35\/03\/2018":"3"},{"31\/03\/2018":"6"},{"31\/03\/2018":"1"}]
```

Comment: Thanks so much =)